# Why my 12V RGB LED strip controlled by Arduino Uno has reversed colors and when I set RGB to 0,0,0 (after reverse) strip should be black but its red?

Tags: rgb, arduino-uno

This is scheme:

Transistors: BD912, PNP, 15A, 100V, 90W, TO220.

[image: scheme]

And this is color of "black":

[image: black strip]

and this is code:

````
const int redPin = 5;
const int greenPin = 6;
const int bluePin = 3;

void setup() {
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  analogWrite(redPin, 255);
  analogWrite(greenPin, 255);
  analogWrite(bluePin, 255);

}
```
````

Comment: The question contains the text ``should be black but its red``. From looking at the picture the actual LEDs appear to be white rather than red. It is the material of the strip which is showing as red.

Comment: There are white LEDs shown here, which is bizzarre if you really have a simple RGB chain as you claim (are you sure they aren't WS2812 or similar? if so, 12v may have caused damage) ... Do the white LEDs move around and/or flicker? Do you _only_ see Red with occasional White? Can you clarify what you mean by "_reversed colors_"? (e.g: what happens if you try to show Red / Green / Blue?) ... don't forget to revise the use of transistors (as already mentioned in an answer).

Comment: Reverse: AnalogWrite(red, 255) should be max value of color instead its minimum
any led is flickering
I dont know what is this strip this is first cheappest led strip i could find

Comment: And this is not argb this is normal rgb strip

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you have a pictorial diagram that is intended to use N-channel MOSFETs and you've subsituted [BD912](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bd911.pdf) PNP transistors (without base resistors).

If accurate, that's not going to work and you may have damaged the Arduino.

Comment: Can you advise me which tranzistor i should buy?

Comment: Can I use  IRFZ44N IR N-MOSFET?

Comment: No, IRLZ44 is suitable for 5V drive. IRFZ44 is not!

Comment: then which I should use?

Comment: IRLZ44 is suitable from a drive point of view. There are many others but most are SMT so not easy to breadboard.

Comment: Very hard to bread board. Anything better?

Comment: They're pretty good if you restricted to through-hole parts.

Answer (score 3):

```
const int redPin = 5;     // Red is wired to pin 6.
const int greenPin = 6;   // Green is wired to pin 9.
const int bluePin = 3;    // Blue wired to pin 5.
```

Comment: I changed this on my board

Comment: @Adamoss, then fix your question. We can only go on the information you have provided.

Comment: I changed pins and same issue, when i write normal colors like 255,0,0 - sea blue 0,255,0 it is purple

Comment: Your question needs to be coherent and consistent. Fix the code to match the wiring cartoon and the photograph.